# Never one to mince his words, Antonio was the perfect dissembler; even an outright fabrication was delivered with aplomb

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, passive-voice, infinitives, subjects

> Never one to mince his words, **Antonio was the perfect dissembler**; even an outright fabrication was delivered with aplomb.

Bold part is OK. However, I am really struggling to understand other parts.

"Never one to mince his words": What is the subject of the sentence? What is the tense used? What does "to" stand for in the sentence?

"even an outright fabrication was delivered with aplomb": Why the sentence is passive past? Does passive past makes the sentence sarcastic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This absolute pattern:

Never one to {verb phrase}, {subject} ...

means that {subject} is someone who never {verbs}

**Never one to drink in moderation, he had six glasses of beer with dinner.**

verb phrase = drink in moderation
subject = he

You can think of it as an inversion:

**He had six glasses of beer with dinner, never (being) one to drink in moderation.**

There is no tensed verb in the absolute clause.

P.S.
We also say things like:

**He was never *one to take* big risks.**

He was not someone who would ever take big risks.

Answer (score 1):

> Never one to mince his words,

Is a dependent clause--not a sentence.  It merely describes Antonio.  It does not contain a subject.  "to" + "mince" = an infinitive, giving the verb *mince* noun-like qualities.  In other words, it allows *mince* to describe *his words* (in light of *never*).

The independent clause

> even an outright fabrication was delivered with aplomb.

is, as you stated, both past tense and of passive voice. 
A sentence that is passive is not necessarily sarcastic and vice-versa.  The sarcastic nature of a sentence lies in the exaggerated description used.

Comment: Thank you. However, I still don't get "Never one to mince his words."What does it mean? What does "to" stand for? Is there no tense or modal?

Comment: "to" allows the verb "mince" to be used as a description of how he never uses his words.

Comment: @diogenes *to mince* is a marked infinitive; for the sense, see [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mince) s.v. mince, sense 2.